# Not able to see the newsletter confirmation message box fully when the top bar stickiness is enabled

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, newsletter, confirmation

When the top bar stickiness is enabled, if I'm subscribe or unsubscribe any newsletter, not able to see the confirmation message box. It was sticky with the top bar. After I scrolled the page too, unable to see the message box.

**When enabled the top bar stickiness:**

[image: top bar sticky enabled]

But when disabled the top bar stickiness, still I'm not able to see the confirmation box. If I scroll down the page, at least I can see the message box.

Can the position of the confirmation message box be displayed below the top bar always? So irrespective of the stickinees, we can see the box always.

**When disabled the top bar stickiness**:

[image: top bar sticky disabled]