# Does Stack Exchange have a mechanism to ask users about changes?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-team

Sometimes we get *fait accompli* declarations like

- [We’ve removed the option to disable the fixed top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368973/232762)

which turn out to get lots of downvotes. I am sure that I don't need to quote more than just that one, as that would be redundant. Those declaration pages also see heavily-upvoted answers from several users.

Surely Stack Exchange staff are aware that those downvotes will happen, but I wonder if they are not allowed to announce proposed changes, only to enact and announce them.

I assume that there is some training for staff so that they are taught that substantial downvoting relates to the idea, not them personally, but has that training desensitised them—*maybe you*—to the possibility that **asking** the relevant communities if a change would be welcome might be a Good Idea?

We, the questioners and answerers (I only write from my own point of view) are often referred to as parts of the community. Why does SE impose abitrary site changes on us as if it (SE) is not part of that community?

**Are Stack Exchange employees *allowed* to ask such questions related to site changes?**

Comment: It is funny you mention community. Stack Overflow (the company and its employees) talk ***a lot*** about community nowadays.