# Profile partially visible in reputation league due to sticky top bar change

Tags: bug, status-review, design, top-bar, reputation-leagues

If I click the achievement link in the "Profile" tab, it opens the reputation league. But my profile is visible partially there, requiring me to scroll up every time.
I think the issue is due to the recent [We’ve removed the option to disable the fixed top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368973/312043) change. Can this be fixed?

**Profile tab:**

> [image: Profile tab]

**Reputation league:**

> [image: Reputation League]

Comment: Just scroll the page? :)

Comment: Adding a userscript that disables the sticky top bar seems to fix it

Comment: I don't think this is new. I have had my top bar sticky for a while and there have generally been places where I have to scroll up slightly because page anchors don't remember the top bar exists. So, yes, bug but it's unlikely related to the change.

Comment: [Very relevant answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368980/348196).

Comment: If a sticky top bar causes bugs, maybe SO should remove the stickiness - we don't want to trouble the company with fixing so many bugs :)

Comment: @Catija in my memory this page always worked fine. Perhaps it was an issue at other pages, but not this one.