# What is reason to forcibly disable left nav on some pages?

Tags: support, design, left-nav

I noticed that on some pages, like:

- [Asking a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)
- Any page related to [review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review)

left navigation is forcibly hidden despite an option in [profile settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current):

> [image: Hide left navigation option]

What is the reason for such behavior?

Comment: All side bars are hidden, not only left. The focus is only on asking a question, or the review task at hand.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 there are no settings to other side bars than left.

Comment: Already reported and marked [tag:status-bydesign] here: [Visual design changes to the review queues](/a/360502/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon seems that the next step will be a "removing the option from settings at all" like as it was done for top-bar stickiness [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368973/339911).